# Single Page Application: page reload

Tags: java, architecture, client-side, single-page-application

I've simple SPA and I make log out on reloading. As I understand the disadvantage of NOT logging out on reloading is to reinitialization of the whole application.

***Questions:***

1. What are the disadvantages of NOT logging off at Single Page Application?
2. What is the best way to achive NOT loging of on reloading (F5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The advantage is that not logging off will avoid pissing off your users so much that they'll want to kill you :-). Seriously, if an application logged me off every time I refresh a page (or open a link in a new tab), I would never use that application again.
2. Well, don't do it. Make sure the authentication token is stored in a place surviving a refresh, i.e. not in some JS variable, but in a cookie or local storage, for example.

Comment: I read that store user credentials in coockies is a bad practice. What do you mean by local storage, and what wiht securityfor that?

Comment: Why would it be a bad practice? That's what done by all non-single page applications. What I mean by local storage is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LocalStorage#localStorage